# Preterito Indefinido or Imperfecto when talking about experiences in the past

Tags: pretérito-imperfecto

I want to ask a question about the difference between *indefinido* and *imperfecto*.

I was watching a video of Angel Di Maria, an Argentinian footballer, and he was asked

> ¿Comó fue Argentina creciendo allí?

I thought however, that seeing as the time period spent growing up didn't have a definite end, I thought that the verb to be used was not *fue* but rather the imperfect version, *era*.

I thought the correct question was

> ¿Comó era Argentina creciendo allí?

Am I correct? - My thoughts were that *fue* was just used in a colloquial sense, but is *era* the grammatically correct verb to use?

Answer (score 8):

Both questions seem strange to me, because they sound as if the person growing up in Argentina could have affected the country in any way, which is absurd.

Actually, a more suitable question would have been:

- *¿Cómo **fue** crecer en Argentina?* (What was it like to grow up in Argentina?) to refer to the final result.

or

- *¿Cómo **era** crecer en Argentina?* (same translation) to refer to the process of growing up, or to some point during the process.